# Bootstrap Tour - navigating to a component on a generated page

Tags: bootstrap-tour

I am trying to navigate to a page that is generated by a MVC controller. Meaning mysite.com/Configure calls Index function in ConfigureController that generates a HTML page.  I want the tour to junp to a particular item on that generated page. The ID of the item is always static.

Adding this step navigates to the configure page but the tour popup is nowhere on sight after the page is automatically navigated via Tour step, like this

```
 {
      path: "/Configure",
      element: "#mysettings",
      title: "Setting",
      content: "some content"
  }
```

I have an inkling that the DOM is not fully created when the tour object tries to create execute the step.  But this should be the same issue with any navigation to another page, even static one because the page may take time to load. So not sure If DOM is the issue.

Another issue I am having is that I want to show tour popup on one of the dropdown items of Bootstrap button group, like this (want to automatically show dropdown and tour popup pointing to #myliid1:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li id="myliid1" role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

My feeling is that it is not possible, but just want to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Issue 1 has been resolved.  Apparently, I needed to call `tour.restart()` on the second page.

Issue 2:  not resolved.  The tour does point to someone in the air when the tour step is pointed to an item in the Bootstrap button group (which turns into a dropdown at runtime), but the dropdown is actually not automatically pulled down.  That would have been magical.  So basically, right now, the tour is limited to things that are visible on the screen.